# Cascade DropdownList, set texts to blank after change

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I'm using 3 drop downlists, getting the data from a local data base. Each of the dropdownlist is being populated from the selection of the dropdownlist above. Kinda like a Country, region, town set up (depending on the country you get a set of regions, depending on the region to get a set of towns) This is working properly using sqldatasource from visual studio 2013.

My problem comes when I change one of the previous dropdownlist values, for example: I have selected a country in dropdownlist1, a region in dropdownlist 2 and a town in dropdownlist3. What I want to do is: when I change the value of dropdownlist1 to another country, set the other 2 to blank.

EDIT FOR CODE

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack ="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="area" DataValueField="area" Font-Bold="True" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [area] FROM [Area]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="categoria" DataValueField="categoria" Font-Bold="True" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" Enabled="False">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Categoria WHERE Categoria.area = @area">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="area" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" DataTextField="problema" DataValueField="problema" Font-Bold="True" Height="16px" Width="250px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList3_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" Enabled="False">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM PROBLEMA WHERE problema.categoria = @categoria;">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList2" Name="categoria" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Without seeing the implementation this is mainly a guess, but can't you simply un-bind those controls when the first one changes?  Basically, clear all of the options from them.  That would remove their selections by default.

Comment: So simple, it worked for reseting the values. But I still can't get them to blank.